# How to send DMX signals via Java?

Tags: java, lighting

(Note; I can't create new tags, however being able to help me would most likely require knowledge about DMX in terms of lighting)

So I want to create my own Lighting software, I'm familiar with Java however I have no idea how to send DMX signals via a Java application.

I have access to a DMX to USB interface (which we currently use alongside LightJockey / Martin-PC), so the exact problem is somehow sending information/DMX-signals though that interface from a java application.

Would be great if there were any existing frameworks/APIs that I could use to just specify an address + value to, although anything to help point me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Did you find anything yet?

Comment: Yeah ended up sending dmx via an arduino using a DMX library I found here; http://blog.deskontrol.net/small-arduino-dmx-controller/